# Requirejs - Loading modules only if a condition is true

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, js-amd

Using Requirejs, how can I load modules only if a condition is true?
example, If the user is Admin, load file the module a.js.

PS: I'm using Backbone with Requirejs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
define([], function () {
    function realWork (modulea) {
        // do stuff ...
        // so stuff with modulea
        if (modulea) {
            ...
        }
    }

    if (isAdmin) {
        require(["modulea"], function (modulea) {
            realWork(modulea);
        });
    } else {
        realWork();
    }
});
```

You might be able to [write your own requirejs plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html) to tidy this up if you find yourself repeating the pattern.

Comment: I would to do also, example, if I click a button load a module....so I just put require(["module"], function(m) {...}) where I want?

Comment: Is there a way to do it synchronously?

Answer (score 1):

OR

```
define(['isAdmin!modelea'], function(modulea){ 
  if (modulea) { 
    // doSomethingWithIt(); 
  } 
});
```